# Scraping with Nokogiri in Ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

How can I get the name and description attributes together and make an island object for each island? I've tried everything I could to get both attributes together to make an object but could only get them separately. I need help as I have to submit this in two days. This is what I have:

```
class MostBeautifulIslands::Islands
  attr_accessor :name, :description

  @@all = []

  def initialize(name)
     @name = name
     @description = description
     @@all << self
  end

  def self.scrape_world_best_islands
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.planetware.com/world/most-beautiful-islands-in-the-world-sey-1-2.htm"))
    islands_names = doc.search("div h2.sitename")
    names = islands_names.collect{|island_name| new(island_name.text.strip)} 
    island_description = doc.search("div.site_desc > p")
    descriptions = island_description.collect{|d| d.first.text.strip}

    new_island = self.new(names)
    new_island

    binding.pry
    #end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimum (stripped) HTML in the question itself. The fact that the code itself loads it doesn't help, it actually slows our ability to help you because we have to wade through that HTML to find what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in `initialize` you use `description` param that is never got. It should be:

```
def initialize(name, description)
  @name = name
  @description = description
  @@all << self
end
```

Secondary, you should collect names, descriptions, and then use these values (zipped) to produce new instances:

```
islands_names = doc.search("div h2.sitename").map(&:text)
islands_descs = doc.search("div.site_desc > p").map(&:text)

islands_names.zip(islands_descs).map { |(name, desc)| new(name, desc) }
#⇒ Array of 15 newly created objects
```

Comment: Thanks Mudasobwa this really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate this into two separate classes. One to handle the Nokogiri parsing and the other to handle the MostBeutifulIslands::Islands object. This gives you a bit more flexibility on handling the data.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri' 

module MostBeutifulIslands
  class Islands
    attr_reader :name, :description

    def initialize(name, description)
      @name = name
      @description = description
    end

    def valid?
      !name.nil? && !description.nil? 
    end

    def save
      # if using rails could save to Islands object
      island =  Island.new(name: name, description: description)

      if island.save
        puts island.save
      else
        puts island.errors
      end
    end
  end
end

module MostBeutifulIslands
  class ParseIslands
    attr_reader :url, :islands

    def initialize(url)
      @url = url
    end

    def html
      Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    end

    def scrap_world_best_islands
      # maybe no need to us each_with_object could do everything you need inside the block
      html.css("div .article_block").css('.site').each_with_object([]).map do |node, array|
        name = node.css('.sitename').text.strip
        description = node.css('.site_desc').text.strip
        @islands = array.push MostBeutifulIslands::Islands.new(name, description)
      end 
    end

    # just an example 
    def save_islands
      @islands.each do |island|
        if island.valid?
          island.save 
        end
      end
    end

    islands = MostBeutifulIslands::ParseIslands.new("http://www.planetware.com/world/most-beautiful-islands-in-the-world-sey-1-2.htm")
    islands.scrap_world_best_islands
    islands.save_islands
  end
end
```